# Some .txt files will open with the wrong encoding

Tags: utf-8, pycharm, python-3.6

I have been working on a project for a while now, and I just reached another big step! However, for some .txt files that my program creates, it will give me this message:

File was loaded in the wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'

Most of the .txt files are fine, but it gives me this error for others at the top (I can still read them). Here is my code:

```
from socket import *
import codecs
import subprocess

ipa = '192.168.1.'  # These are the first 3 digits of the IP addresses that the program looks for.


def is_up(adr):
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(0.01)
    if not s.connect_ex((adr, 135)):
        s.close()
        return 1
    else:
        s.close()


def main():
    for i in range(1, 256):
        adr = ipa + str(i)
        if is_up(adr):
            with codecs.open("" + getfqdn(adr) + ".txt", "w+", 'utf-8-sig') as f:
                subprocess.run('ipconfig | findstr /i "ipv4"', stdout=f, shell=True, check=True)
                subprocess.run('wmic/node:'+adr+' product get name, version, vendor', stdout=f, shell=True, check=True)


main()

# Most code provided by Ashish Jain
```

Unfortunately I don't think I'm allowed to say exactly which files are giving me trouble, because I might be distributing information that someone can use for malicious intent.

Comment: Your code only writes to files. What code reads them and gives you the said error message?

Comment: I actually found out that it will usually happen on files with bigger lines.

Comment: To answer your question, there is no code that reads them (I wasn't even sure it would be necessary), and the error only shows up when I open it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your script only writes to files, there's no reason to open it in `w+` mode, which enables reading. Opening the files in `w` mode should be enough.

Furthermore, the commands that your script runs must not be outputting in `utf-8-sig`-encoded text, and hence the error. In most cases outputting with default encoding by not specifying an encoding will suffice.

Lastly, you're missing a space between `wmic` and `/node:` in the second command you run.

Comment: should I still use codecs or can I just set a variable to open a file?

Comment: @fread I think the real problem here is that `ipconfig` outputs in ANSI while `wmic` outputs in UTF-16 so their outputs should not be directly merged in one file without normalizing them to the same encoding. You should use `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', text)` for that. Don't think `codecs` is needed.

Comment: I changed my ipconfig to an echo command (instead of following the ipconfig command, which prints the same IP address for every file, it instead echoes the correct IP address). Should I still use unicodedata, and if so, how should it be implemented? I'm not very familiar with the unicodedata module.